# About the existence of a generic point on an irreducible closed subset of a prescheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is Proposition 2 on page 81 of Mumford's *The Red Book of Varieties and Schemes*:

> Let $X$ be a prescheme, and $Z \subset X$ an irreducible closed subset. Then there is one and only one point $z \in Z$ such that $Z = \overline{\{ z \}}$.
>
> *Proof*. Let $U \subset X$ be an open affine set such that $Z \cap U \neq \emptyset$. Then any point $z \in Z$ dense in $Z$ must be in $Z \cap U$; and a point $z \in Z \cap U$ whose closure contains $Z \cap U$ is also dense in $Z$. Therefore it suffices to prove the theorem for the closed subset $Z \cap U$. But by Prop. 1 of section 4 there is a unique $z \in Z \cap U$ dense in $Z \cap U$.

I have some questions about this proof.

1. Why does every dense point in $Z$ lie in $Z \cap U$?
2. Why must $z \in Z \cap U$ whose closure contains $Z \cap U$ be dense in $Z$?
3. Why is there a unique $z \in Z \cap U$ dense in $Z \cap U$? I can't find the proposition the author mentioned.

I think these are concerned with affineness, but I don't know the exact reason.

Thanks for everyone.

Comment: 1. this is just by density, every non-empty open subset of $Z$ must intersect the dense set $\overline{\{z\}}$, and since $Z\cap U$ is open and non-empty, it intersects it.

2. Since $Z$ is irreducible every open subset is dense, so if $\overline{\{z\}}$ contains $Z\cap U$ it contains a dense set, and thus must be $Z$. 

3.  I don't know what the proposition says. It may be something of the form $\text{Spec}(A)$ is irreducible if and only if $A$ has a unique minimal prime. The unique minimal prime would be the unique generic point.

Comment: Dear @Alex, I hadn't seen your comment when I answered. I would probably have abstained if I had...Anyway, +1.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Don't worry the more intelligent writing on the internet to hold back the refuse, the better :)

Comment: @Alex: thanks. By the way, it seems that your mastership of algebraic geometry is rocketing: bravo!

Comment: What the author mentioned is Prop 1 of Section 1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) A point $z$ dense in $Z$ must belong to any non-empty open subset of $Z$, so in particular to $Z\cap U$.
2) Any non-empty open subset $V\subset Z$ of an irreducible space $Z$ is dense: $\overline V=Z$.
So  applying this to $V=Z\cap U$ we get $\overline {\{z\}}\supset \overline {Z\cap U}=\overline V=Z$, so that $\overline {\{z\}}=Z.$
3) Any non-empty open subset of an irreducible space $Z$ is irreducible, so   $V=Z\cap U$  is irreducible. 
Hence  $V\subset U$ is a closed irreducible subset of $U=\operatorname {Spec R}$.
By basic affine scheme theory $V=V(\mathfrak p)$   for some prime ideal $\mathfrak p\subset R$ and $[\mathfrak p]=z\in V$ is the required dense point of $V$.

Comment: I don't understand why 2) should imply it is sufficient to prove the theorem for $Z\cap U$

Comment: @Susobhan: 1)+2) say that the points of $S$ dense in $Z$ are exactly the same as the points of $Z\cap U$ dense in $Z\cap U$.

Comment: It should be points of $Z$ dense in $Z$, right? not S? Should be a typo.

Comment: @Susobahn: yes, you are right, it was  a typo, now corrected.